# Error with Pluggable Workflow Service while debugging

Tags: workflow

I was debugging my first pluggable service and I got this error just when I pressed F11 to test this:

[image]

That's the error, any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: I think it was because of I was missing something on the web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you are missing the web.config entry that registers your Plugable WF Service.